# Votes by Community aren't updated live

Tags: bug, community-user, live-refresh

Okay, I've got one more.

If [Community](/users/-1/community) downvotes a post (as it is wont to do when someone deems it spam, offensive, or off topic), that vote isn't pushed out as a real-time update.

If you've flagged any post as spam/offensive recently, you've probably seen this. The flag is immediately followed up with a downvote, but you won't see it until you refresh the page (or of course, someone else who is not Community also downvotes it).